# Find middle element of LinkedList

Tags: java, linked-list

```
    private static String findMiddleElementOfLinkedList(Node head) {
        if (head == null) {
            return null;
        }
        Node slowCursor = head;
        if (slowCursor.next != null) {
            Node fastCursor = head.next.next;
            while (fastCursor != null) {
                slowCursor = slowCursor.next;
                fastCursor = fastCursor.next.next;
            }
        }

        return String.valueOf(slowCursor.data);
    }
}
```

Comment: there has to be some kind of question here (preferably with some context)

Comment: It's also completely broken for odd-length lists (due to the unchecked `fastCursor.next.next`).  Please [edit] the question to include your test set.

Answer (score 1):

`fastCursor = fastCursor.next.next;` will crash if the number of nodes in the list is even (but greater than zero).

Comment: Can you provide me with an example of this case? I tested this code with one node, two nodes and 6 nodes.

Comment: You need to try 4 :)